# What is the angle the measure of the angle formed by BC and the straight line that passes through the orthocenter and the circumcenter?

Tags: geometry

For reference: In a triangle ABC; calculate the measure of the angle formed by BC and the straight line that passes through the orthocenter and the circumcenter($\measuredangle OEC=?$)

My progress...
I made the drawing and marked the found angles

H is orthocenter
C is circumcenter

[image]

Solutionby MathLover:

[image]

Comment: Is there a unique value of the angle? Also is the angle $120^{\circ}$ given?

Comment: @Narasimham..It is mentioned in the question which angle was requested..$\measuredangle OEC$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $ \small \angle ABC = 120^\circ$ in $ \small \triangle ABC$.

As $H$ is the orthocenter, $ \small \angle AHC = 180^\circ - \angle ABC = 60^\circ$. If you are not familiar with this, see the end of the answer where I show it.

$ \therefore \small AOCH$ is a cyclic quadrilateral ($ \small \angle AHC + \angle AOC = 180^\circ$).

So $ \small \angle CHO = \angle CAO = 30^\circ$

$ \small \angle CEO = \angle CHO + \angle HCE = 60^\circ$

---

If you want to show $ \small \angle AHC = 60^\circ$, note that as $ \small H$ is the orthocenter, $ \small AH$ will be perpendicular to $ \small BC$ so $ \small \angle BAH = 30^\circ$.

Say $ \small \angle ACB = x$. Then,

$ \small \angle GHC = 90^\circ - \angle GCH = 90^\circ - (30^\circ + x) = 60^\circ - x$

$ \small \angle GHA = 90^\circ - \angle GAH = 90^\circ - (60^\circ - x + 30^\circ) = x$

$ \small \angle AHC = \angle GHA + \angle GHC = 60^\circ$

Comment: excellent...admirable your facility with geometry...hope my posts aren't being exaggerated...a detail...what relation did you use for $\measuredangle AOC = 120^o$?thank you as always for the help

Comment: @petaarantes chord $AC$ subtends $120^\circ$ at point $B$ so will subtend $180^\circ - 120^\circ = 60^\circ$ at any point on the circle on the other side of the center. So it will subtend double the angle at the center.

Comment: Can you tell how $\angle GAH=60^\circ-x+30^\circ$?

Comment: @ACB as $\angle ACB = x$ (yes ACB :)), $\angle BAC = 60^\circ - x$. Also $\angle BAH = 30^\circ$. Adding them we get $\angle GAH$.

Comment: : D, but now my problem is how $\angle BAH=30^\circ$. Sometime my eyes miss obvious clues.

Comment: As $H$ is orthocenter, $AH \perp CB$. Say they intersect at $P$. Then $\angle APB = 90^\circ$. Also, we have $\angle ABP = 60^\circ$. So $\angle BAH = 30^\circ$

Comment: @ACB Not only you... in these questions with many lines it's easy to miss out on clues